# Hadoop - executing multi-Map-jobs

Tags: java, hadoop

I have an application that only implement Map function.
I'm creating 1000 jobs, each with a unique PrefixFilter.
Example:

```
public void startNewScan(String prefix, long endTime)
    Job job = new Job(conf, "MyJob");
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

    Scan scan = new Scan();

    scan.setTimeRange(0, endTime);
    scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("col"), Bytes.toBytes("Value"));
    scan.setFilter(new PrefixFilter(prefix.getBytes()));

    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(tableName, scan, ExtractMapper.class, ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class, job);
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
}
```

Now - I don't want to wait for completion, because executing 1000 jobs would take me forever. Creating a thread for each job is also not an option.
Is there anything built in for this usage? 
Something like JobsPool that accepts all the jobs and has its own waitForCompletion for all the jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
job.submit();

"Submit the job to the cluster and return immediately."
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw this function, but the thing is that once its done I don't have a way to know weather what I did was successful or not, and I lose any indication for exception thrown in the process..

Comment: @Udi There seems to be methods such as `isComplete()`, `isRetired()`, etc., in the [API](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html)